# Randomly occuring Unexpected end of JSON on GET request

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I'm developing a simple web project where one of the features (Related to the error) will display a quote, credit and source. This feature works as intended using `setInterval` every 12seconds to call a function which will make a connection to my XAMPP hosted MYSQL server and return a random row as a `JSON` object which I can use to display on the page. below is the Quote retrieval script and PHP:

**quotes.js**

```
(function() {
  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var method = "GET";
  var url = "data.php";
  var asynchronous = true; // revise asynchronous

  var quoteContainer = document.getElementById("quote");
  var authorContainer = document.getElementById("author");

  function getQuote() {

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(data)

        quoteContainer.innerHTML =  "\"" + data.Quote + "\""
        authorContainer.innerHTML = data.Author + " - " + "<a href='"+ data.Source +"' target='_blank'>source</a>";

      }

    }

    ajax.open(method,url,asynchronous);
    ajax.send();
  }

  getQuote();
  setInterval(getQuote,12000); //set to 100 for testing

}());
```

**Data.php**

```
<?php
// write secondry query for seasonal messages
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quotes_db");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quote_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The issue is that on random occasions while this is running the server returns a 'null' packet (with the titled error) I have checked the network data using Chromes developer console and the effected packets are empty and take slightly longer to return. I have checked my database table for special characters and it all seems normal. due to the packet returning null the page is left empty

1. How can I stop this error appearing, so that I can get a continuous stream of random rows from my table?
2. If the answer is not an obvious one what bug-testing steps should I take to find a fix?

If more information is needed I can update this post.

**Error log**

[image]

Comment: What is `console.log(data)` returning in the abovementioned case?

Comment: Any possibility to share your code and a database dump? I would then try it out and try to propose a solution as the ones below only cover error handling (what is important as well of course).

Comment: I've recreated your code and database and it works perfectly fine for me. Can you please share your database scheme or an export?

Comment: Thank you for your DB dump! I was able to find the issue and added my explanation to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your encoding: `Jean de La Bruyère` is transmitted as `Jean de La Bruy�re` by MySQL.

PHP `json_encode()` is not able to deal with the encoding of the French character as shown in this `print_r()` output of the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` result:

```php
Array
(
    [QuoteID] => 6
    [Quote] => Those who make the worst use of their time are the first to complain of its brevity.
    [Author] => Jean de La Bruy�re
    [Source] => https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/778012.Jean_de_La_Bruy_re
)
```

As `json_encode()` is only accepting UTF-8 encoded strings (["All string data must be UTF-8 encoded."](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), cf. PHP Documentation), you can tell MySQL to return every result in UTF-8 encoding by simply executing the following query once after opening the connection:

```php
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Comment: This looks like the fix, thanks for the taking the time to recreate the error I'll accept your solution once I implement it

Answer (score 2):

You can do some kind of error handling to achieve your goal.

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        try
        {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            if (error instanceof SyntaxError)
            {
                // unable to parse the result to json
                // maybe retry?
                // do some kind of errer handling
            }
        }
      }
```

Using the try-catch statement you simply catch the error instead of stopping the script from executing so you are able to handle errors yourself.

Best regards.

EDIT:

```
setInterval(function () 
{ 
    var found = false; 
    var attemptCount = 0;
    var allowedAttempts = 10; // your exit condition, so you wont get stuck in an infinite loop if the server is broken or something
    while (!found && attemptCount < allowedAttempts) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            getQuote(); 
        } 
        catch (error) 
        { 
            if (error instanceof SyntaxError) 
            { 
                attemptCount++;
                continue; 
            } 
        } 
        found = true; 
    } 
}, 12e3);
```

EDIT No.2: (based on your comment on another answer)
If you want to do some server-side validation, you have to modify the PHP-Code:

```
$data = []; // set a default return value
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) // we found a result
{
    $data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

So, if you combine both, the client- and server-side validation you should be fine for sure:

What did we do?

- we implemented a server side validation, so the result that is returned to the client should never throw an error when going through `JSON.parse()`. To make this work you have to implement a client-side validation on the result of `JSON.parse()` to make sure that you got a valid result (because it could be an empty array).
- if any errors occur on the server (for whatever reason) and the returned result cannot be parsed, we simply retry the entire process for n times.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Error handling is a good idea I didn't think of it, although wouldn't that just cover up the issue? The way the page works is every 12s a new quote is displayed, but when the error occurs it returns nothing and leaves the space blank. Would I just call getQuote() in the catch?

Comment: In this case you need to change the entire structure:
setInterval(function ()
{
var found = false;
while (!found)
{
    try
    {
        getQuote();
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        if (error instanceof SyntaxError)
        {
             continue;
        }
    }
    found = true;
}
}, 12e3);

But keep in mind that this implementation has no exit condition. You have to adapt it still to, for example let the while loop process max. 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the data returned is undefined or is not in a valid format. That is when JSON.parse() would fail. You can consider putting try-catch block.

```
try {
   var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
} catch(e) {
   console.log('Unable to parse the string.')
}
```

Also, consider wrapping the JSON.parse() statement in an if condition, if server sends an empty response.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. like I said to Bar Ger try/catch maybe part of the solution but it doesn't explain why it's returning null or in a format that can't be read. I entered the data for the quotes table by hand(copy & paste). the table contains an auto-incrementing ID, an author, quote text (without speech marks) and a URL to a source. I have exported my table to JSON for readability and it seems to look normal